# Stuck with Soap and PHP

Tags: php, soap

So i'm trying to access a simple java method via php using wsdl and soap. But when I try to run the php file it shows me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass' : Extra content at the end of the document in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\abc.php(2): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://localhos...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc.php on line 2

Here's my code:

```
<?php  
  $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass");
 $name=15;
 $c=20;
  $response = $client->demo($name, $c);
  echo $response;
?>
```

I'm not able to figure out what the problem is. Is it the argument to the `SoapClient` constructor? Does it have to be given following some other syntax?

And also i'm a complete newbie in Soap and WSDL so a step-by-step solution will be appreciated!

Comment: "http://localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass" must be a path to ur WSDL file, is it?

Comment: I think so, but i'm not that sure. Actually the WSDL file of the java code which I am trying to access via php was created by Eclipse itself as part of the Dynamic Web Project. There it provided this unique path which i pasted in the SoapClient constructor. So is the path wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass the WSDL of the service to the SOAP constructor, can be also a file on localhost. Usually simple add ?wsdl to che service url.

```
<?php  
  $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass?wsdl");
 $name=15;
 $c=20;
  $response = $client->demo($name, $c);
  echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The old error is gone but now i have been greeted by the following annoying error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass?wsdl" in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\abc.php(2): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://localhos...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc.php on line 2

Comment: As I say, you need a (valid) WSDL and the URL  localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass?wsdl is not a WSDL. What do you know about your service? Does exist the URL localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass ? Try to open with a browser (firefox or chrome shows the XML) your service url:   localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass or localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass?wsdl and report what you see. Ty

Comment: No it's a valid WSDL URL, actually the problem was with my server apache tomcat. I changed it to JBOSS and everything worked fine! :). But now there's another problem - whenever i try to call the java function from my SoapClient object and pass arguments to it, the following error occurs - Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.generalException] Tried to invoke method public int Sample.demo(int) with arguments null. The arguments do not match the signature.; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc.php:3 
Now what is this?? Help please!

Comment: If you need help, ask help. Close this question and open new one (the previous comment it's already enought)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you're not declaring the file extension of the wsdl,

Change this,

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass");
```

to this,

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/WEB/services/SampleClass.wsdl");
```

Comment: That is not a common way of calling for the wsdl.

Answer (score -1):

I once had this problem too. The source was a missing quote.

xmlns:myorder="app/orders/